# Laravel Master Layout is being evaluated when using another layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I've been trying to make a set of variables available within blade layout files e.i.

- layouts/master.blade.php
- layouts/admin.php

The variable i'm using is called $sitesettings->sitetitle.

I'm outputting this variable like so:

```
    <title>{{ $sitesettings->sitetitle }}</title>
```

This variable is populated within the BaseController:

```
class BaseController extends Controller 
{

    public function __construct()
    {   
        View::share('sitesettings', SiteSetting::find(1));
    }

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        if ( !is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is when i access the admin layout. The master seems to be getting evaluated before hand and the following error occurs.

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: sitesettings (View: /home/vagrant/Code/DanielDelCore/laravel/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php) (View: /home/vagrant/Code/DanielDelCore/laravel/app/views/layouts/master.blade.php)
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly this problem occurs, but I suggest you use a different approach. [View composers](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers).

```
View::composer(['layouts.master', 'layouts.admin'], function($view){
    $view->with('sitesettings', SiteSetting::find(1));
});
```

You can put this code in `app/filters.php` or create a new `app/composers.php` and include it at the end of `app/start/global.php` with:

```
require app_path().'/composers.php';
```